# Probability of picking balls without replacement

Tags: probability

Jar contains 14 balls - 5 reds,4 blue,3 green and 2 yellow. I grab 4 balls at once. What is the probability I get 2 reds,1 blue and 1 green balls (order does not matter).

I can compute the probability for specific sequence say red,red green blue
but there are many of them so this looks cumbersome. I wonder what is the standard way to solve this problem without listing explicitly all valid sequences.

Thanks!

Comment: You solve problems like this by counting combinations.  Number the balls so that they're distinguishable.  Count the number of combinations that result in $2$ reds, $1$ blue, and $1$ green.  Divide that by the total number of combinations.

Comment: Another approach that yields the same answer is to augment the problem to make it something you already know how to solve, yet the outcome is what you are looking for. Suppose we add intermediate steps to draw the balls one at a time in order. Once we have 4, we stop and collect them in a pile. We wind up with the same outcome as grabbing four at a time. Except now, you have a sequence which you already know how to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of (equally likely) outcomes is $14 \choose 4$
For a outcome to be favorable, you need to get 2 red balls out of 5, 1 blue out of 4, 1 green out of 3 and 0 yellow out of 2, so the total number of favorable outcomes is:
${5\choose 2}{4\choose 1}{3\choose 1}{2\choose 0}$
So the probability you are looking for is:

$$\frac{{5\choose 2}{4\choose 1}{3\choose 1}{2\choose 0}}{14 \choose 4}$$